# Filter on recyclerview does not working properly on android level 19, 21, 22, 23

Tags: android, filter, android-recyclerview

The code is working good in android level up 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30.., but unfortunately this code is not working properly in below level 23 ex: 22, 21, 20, 19..,
Below is MyAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<User> listaContactos;
    ArrayList<User> listaOriginal;

    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<User> listaContactos) {
        this.listaContactos = listaContactos;
        listaOriginal = new ArrayList<>();
        listaOriginal.addAll(listaContactos);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_item_contacto, null, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.viewNombre.setText(listaContactos.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.viewTelefono.setText(listaContactos.get(position).getTelefono());
        holder.viewCorreo.setText(listaContactos.get(position).getCorreo_electornico());
    }

    public void filtrado(final String txtBuscar) {
        int longitud = txtBuscar.length();
        if (longitud == 0) {
            listaContactos.clear();
            listaContactos.addAll(listaOriginal);
        } else {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                List<User> collecion = listaOriginal.stream()
                        .filter(i -> i.getNombre().toLowerCase().contains(txtBuscar.toLowerCase()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                listaContactos.clear();
                listaContactos.addAll(collecion);
            } else {
                for (User c : listaOriginal) {
                    if (c.getNombre().toLowerCase().contains(txtBuscar.toLowerCase())) {
                        listaContactos.clear();
                        listaContactos.add(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaContactos.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView viewNombre, viewTelefono, viewCorreo;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            viewNombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewNombre);
            viewTelefono = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewTelefono);
            viewCorreo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewCorreo);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Context context = view.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, VerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ID", listaContactos.get(getAdapterPosition()).getID());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Below is MainActivity

```
package com.example.buscar_en_listas_de_belajarrecyclerviewsearch;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

//    SearchView txtBuscar;
    SearchView txtBuscar;
    RecyclerView listaContactos;
    ArrayList<User> listaArrayContactos;
    FloatingActionButton fabNuevo;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtBuscar = findViewById(R.id.txtBuscar);
        listaContactos = findViewById(R.id.listaContactos);
        fabNuevo = findViewById(R.id.favNuevo);
        listaContactos.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        DBUser dbContactos = new DBUser(MainActivity.this);

        listaArrayContactos = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new MyAdapter(dbContactos.mostrarContactos());
        listaContactos.setAdapter(adapter);

        fabNuevo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                nuevoRegistro();
            }
        });

        txtBuscar.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_principal, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menuNuevo:
                nuevoRegistro();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void nuevoRegistro(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NuevoActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        adapter.filtrado(s);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Below is MyfullSourcecode.

__drive.google.com/file/d/1xhLeobqOgsoW80V9PjMiYT81PZMkMAou/view

(please remove underscore at the beginning and paste on your browser)

I have searched and modified that code for days so far I have had no luck with this code, I am sorry, I am new in android studio, I only understand the basic code of java.

Modifiying code and make it work properly on android level 19, 20 , 21, 22, 23..

Comment: Enable [desugaring](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/desugaring-in-android/) and you should be able to use your streams filter logic for all android versions.(won't need android N check).

Comment: – Nitish, Thank you, I have tested this in version 19, 20 21, 22, 23 and finally, it works, you save my day..